# remove (Excel) namespace from xml in python 3 ... without using lxml

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xml, namespaces

There are quite alot of posts on removing namespaces in Python, but nearly all use the lxml package.  Which seems very nice, but I've had trouble implementing in Windows.

What I want to achieve with my tags is similar to to:
[removing namespace aliases from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30613580/9249533)
but that answer is oriented toward json and doesn't seem to be python-based.

Similarly, I'm unclear on how to implement this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61786754/9249533

This older post is somewhat helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160058/9249533

But I'm wondering as of July 2021 what the options are?

FWIW, my data look like:
[image]

My aim is to just access the data.  I do not care to move it back to Excel.

presently, if I run:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(in_path + 'myfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter():
    print(child.tag)
```

returns this for the 'Data' tag:

> {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data

I'd like it to just be:

> Data

The prefix/namespace is hampering my very modest xml interpretation skills. Any guidance for doing this with Packages that are more readily Windows compatible (or better still with conda installs) much appreciated.

Comment: The first six lines of your XML contain 3 default `xmlns=` namespaces, and a handful of other namespaces. I really don't know if they are necessary to be distinctive. So removing all of them may be considered a risk. But it could easily be achieved with XSLT. Even with version 1.0.

Comment: To remove all namespaces from all elements and attributes, you can use the first code sample (the first code from the question) from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26659460/1305969).

Comment: Cheers for suggestion, I'll have a look at XSLT and the other post

Comment: "I've had trouble implementing in Windows". Please be more specific. lxml works fine on Windows. Here is a way to remove namespaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972010/407651

Comment: @mzjn cheers for link. Happy to hear you've had success with lxml in Windows. I've had troublesome installs....have not kept accurate records on how/why though.